# Android touches: Drawn circles change their color on touch

Tags: android, touch, drawing, android-view, multi-touch

I want to draw a circle with every touch in random color. I could do that, but every time I touch the screen to draw another circle, previous circles change their color to the same one.  I want already drawn circles to save their color. How can I do that ?

Here is my code: (MainActivity is the same as generated, so I don't put it here)

```
public class Pointer {
    PointF f;
    int color;

    public Pointer(PointF f, int color){
        this.f = f;
        this.color=color;
    }
}
```

And MyView:

```
public class MyView extends View {

Random random = new Random();
PointF f;
public int colors[] = {Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE,
        Color.MAGENTA, Color.DKGRAY, Color.RED,
        Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW};

private static final int SIZE = 80;
Paint paint;
private ArrayList<Pointer> activePointers;


public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    activePointers = new ArrayList<Pointer>();
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int ptrIndex = event.getActionIndex();
    int ptrID = event.getPointerId(ptrIndex);
    int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();
    f = new PointF();
    switch (maskedAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            int color;
            color = random.nextInt(colors.length);

            paint.setColor(colors[color]);
            Pointer pointer = new Pointer(f, color);
            pointer.f.x = event.getX(ptrIndex);
            pointer.f.y = event.getY(ptrIndex);
            activePointers.add(ptrID, pointer);
        }
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                Pointer pointer = activePointers.get(event.getPointerId(i));
                if (pointer != null) {
                    pointer.f.x = event.getX(i);
                    pointer.f.y = event.getY(i);
                }
            }
            break;

    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for (int i = 0; i < activePointers.size(); i++) {
        Pointer pointer = activePointers.get(i);
        if (pointer != null) {
            canvas.drawCircle(pointer.f.x, pointer.f.y, SIZE, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Create a class with a `PointF` and an `int` as members. Change your `ArrayList` to be of that type. Generate the random color index in the `DOWN` touch actions, and create a new instance of your custom class with the `PointF` and random `int` to add to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Well, I did how you said. Now with every touch all the circles change to the same color.

Comment: If you want to edit your question with your current code, I'll have a look.

Comment: Yes, in 2 mins. Thanks!

Comment: You want to leave the `paint.setColor()` call in the `for` loop in `onDraw()`. `paint.setColor(colors[pointer.color]);`

Comment: GENIUS ! Simply a genius! Thanks a lot. You saved me today.